# How can I get all horizontal combinations of an array of arrays in cocoa/objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa

I have a given matrix (array of arrays) like this:

```
NSArray *line1 = @[@"a1",@"b1",@"c1"];
NSArray *line2 = @[@"a2",@"b2",@"c2"];
NSArray *line3 = @[@"a3",@"b3",@"c3"];
NSArray *line4 = @[@"a4",@"b4",@"c4"];

NSArray *matrix = @[fret1,fret2,fret3];
```

It is defined, that the count of each line is the same, but I don't know, how many lines and how  many entries each line has.

I like to get all possible variations of the values from each row.

So I have this code, which works:

```
    NSArray *line1 = @[@"a1",@"b1",@"c1"];
    NSArray *line2 = @[@"a2",@"b2",@"c2"];
    NSArray *line3 = @[@"a3",@"b3",@"c3"];
    NSArray *line4 = @[@"a4",@"b4",@"c4"];

    NSArray *matrix = @[line1,line2,line3,line4];

    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:50];

    NSInteger colCount = matrix.count;
    NSInteger rowCount = [(NSArray*)[matrix objectAtIndex:0] count];

    for (int lc1 = 0; lc1 < colCount; lc1++) {
        for (int lc2 = 0; lc2 < colCount; lc2++) {
            for (int lc3 = 0; lc3 < colCount; lc3++) {
                        NSString *row1 = [(NSArray*)[matrix objectAtIndex:lc1] objectAtIndex:0];
                        NSString *row2 = [(NSArray*)[matrix objectAtIndex:lc2] objectAtIndex:1];
                        NSString *row3 = [(NSArray*)[matrix objectAtIndex:lc3] objectAtIndex:2];

                        [result addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@„,row1,row2,row3]];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < result.count; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%2ld: %@",(long)i,(NSString*)[result objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
```

The code above gives the following result:

```
 0: a1 b1 c1
 1: a1 b1 c2
 2: a1 b1 c3
 3: a1 b1 c4
 4: a1 b2 c1
 5: a1 b2 c2
 6: a1 b2 c3
 7: a1 b2 c4
 8: a1 b3 c1
 9: a1 b3 c2
10: a1 b3 c3
11: a1 b3 c4
12: a1 b4 c1
13: a1 b4 c2
14: a1 b4 c3
15: a1 b4 c4
16: a2 b1 c1
17: a2 b1 c2
18: a2 b1 c3
19: a2 b1 c4
20: a2 b2 c1
21: a2 b2 c2
22: a2 b2 c3
23: a2 b2 c4
24: a2 b3 c1
25: a2 b3 c2
26: a2 b3 c3
27: a2 b3 c4
28: a2 b4 c1
29: a2 b4 c2
30: a2 b4 c3
31: a2 b4 c4
32: a3 b1 c1
33: a3 b1 c2
34: a3 b1 c3
35: a3 b1 c4
36: a3 b2 c1
37: a3 b2 c2
38: a3 b2 c3
39: a3 b2 c4
40: a3 b3 c1
41: a3 b3 c2
42: a3 b3 c3
43: a3 b3 c4
44: a3 b4 c1
45: a3 b4 c2
46: a3 b4 c3
47: a3 b4 c4
48: a4 b1 c1
49: a4 b1 c2
50: a4 b1 c3
51: a4 b1 c4
52: a4 b2 c1
53: a4 b2 c2
54: a4 b2 c3
55: a4 b2 c4
56: a4 b3 c1
57: a4 b3 c2
58: a4 b3 c3
59: a4 b3 c4
60: a4 b4 c1
61: a4 b4 c2
62: a4 b4 c3
63: a4 b4 c4
```

But how can I do this dynamically, because I don't know how many rows and columns I have at compile time?

Comment: stringByAppendingString

Comment: Note that in your code, every combination is listed 4 times because of the inner loop using `lc4`. In your case there are only 4*4*4 = 64 different combinations.

Comment: yeah stupid me - as you can see I was really tired at that moment ;-) I changed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define a function which appends all elements of one column of your matrix to all
previously obtained combinations:

```
NSArray *combinations(NSArray *a, NSArray *matrix, NSUInteger column)
{
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *elem in a) {
        for (NSArray *row in matrix) {
            NSString *tmp = [elem stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", row[column]];
            [result addObject:tmp];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then the following gives the wanted result (and works for an arbitrary number
of rows and columns):

```
NSArray *line1 = @[@"a1",@"b1",@"c1"];
NSArray *line2 = @[@"a2",@"b2",@"c2"];
NSArray *line3 = @[@"a3",@"b3",@"c3"];
NSArray *line4 = @[@"a4",@"b4",@"c4"];
NSArray *matrix = @[line1,line2,line3,line4];

NSArray *result = @[@""];
for (NSUInteger column = 0; column < [line1 count]; column++) {
    result = combinations(result, matrix, column);
}

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [result count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%2lu: %@",(unsigned long)i,(NSString*)[result objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

To understand how this works, let's see what happens in each step of the loop.
In the first step, all elements of column #0 are appended to the empty string:

```
 0:  a1
 1:  a2
 2:  a3
 3:  a4
```

In the second step, all elements of column #1 are appended to all strings from the
first step:

```
 0:  a1 b1
 1:  a1 b2
 2:  a1 b3
 3:  a1 b4
 4:  a2 b1
 5:  a2 b2
 6:  a2 b3
 7:  a2 b4
 8:  a3 b1
 9:  a3 b2
10:  a3 b3
11:  a3 b4
12:  a4 b1
13:  a4 b2
14:  a4 b3
15:  a4 b4
```

In the third step, all elements of column #2 are appended to all strings from 
the second step:

```
 0:  a1 b1 c1
 1:  a1 b1 c2
 2:  a1 b1 c3
 3:  a1 b1 c4
 4:  a1 b2 c1
 5:  a1 b2 c2
 6:  a1 b2 c3
...
58:  a4 b3 c3
59:  a4 b3 c4
60:  a4 b4 c1
61:  a4 b4 c2
62:  a4 b4 c3
63:  a4 b4 c4
```

That's all in your example (with three columns), but it works the same way for more
columns or rows.

Comment: @BlackFrog: I would love to know :-)

Comment: This is a great answer, because it will build the combination of any size matrix.

Comment: perfect solution, thank you - couldn't get my head around this - puh :-)

Answer (score 1):

@MartinR has shown a nice iterative solution, here is a recursive one using blocks for those who think recursively/just for fun :-):

```
NSArray *line1 = @[@"a1",@"b1",@"c1"];
NSArray *line2 = @[@"a2",@"b2",@"c2"];
NSArray *line3 = @[@"a3",@"b3",@"c3"];
NSArray *line4 = @[@"a4",@"b4",@"c4"];

NSArray *matrix = @[line1,line2,line3,line4];

NSUInteger colCount = matrix.count;
NSUInteger rowCount = [matrix[0] count];

NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];

NSMutableArray *sample = [NSMutableArray new];

__block __unsafe_unretained void (^weakCombinations)(NSUInteger);
void (^combinations)(NSUInteger);
weakCombinations = combinations = ^(NSUInteger row)
{
    if (row == rowCount)
    {
        // have a complete sample
        [result addObject:[sample componentsJoinedByString:@" "]];
    }
    else
    {
        // iterate over current column and recurse
        for (NSUInteger ix = 0; ix < colCount; ix++)
        {
            sample[row] = matrix[ix][row];
            weakCombinations(row+1);
        }
    }
};

combinations(0);

for (int i = 0; i < result.count; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%2ld: %@",(long)i,(NSString*)[result objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

The algorithm is straightforward, a sample path through the matrix is constructed and when the end of the row reached the path is joined with spaces and added to the solution set.

*Note: Recursive blocks used to be a little less messy, but under ARC a `__block` variable is retained so we need to do the dance with the `weakCombinations`. The use of `__unsafe_unretained` is safe here, and slightly more efficient than using `__weak`, and as we're using blocks which have calling performance closer to functions than methods why not shave a little more off?*